# How can I set a variable inside a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, variables

got this function to check if the username is an admin.

```
module.exports = {
 checkAdmin: function(username){
  var _this = this;
  var admin = null;
  sql.execute(sql.format('SELECT * FROM tbl_admins'), (err, result, fields) => {
    if (err) {
        logger.error(err.message);
        return;
    }
    adminArray = []
    result.forEach(element => {
        if(element.Username == username){
            adminArray.push(element.Username)
        }
    });
    
    if (adminArray.includes(username)){
      _this.admin = true;
    }else{
      _this.admin = false;
    }
})
return admin;
```

}
}

And this is in the Express file.

```js
var check = Admin.checkAdmin(req.body.username);
if (check == false) {
  console.log("Wrong")
  res.send({
    message: 'Access denied'
  }); //bad request
  return;
}
```

The SQL is correct. The problem is to set the variable "admin" inside the SQL function. The function returns "".

Thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Pass a callback function to your `checkAdmin` which is passed the value of check inside the SQL query handler. Right now you are just returning the value null since the query handler has not even executed.

Comment: If i done it right, the error appeard: 

callback is not a function
callback(false);
@AbrarHossain

Comment: Looks like your **return admin;** is located outside your function looking at your code. And your **_this.admin = true;** and **_this.admin = false;** should just be **admin = true;** since what your returning is admin

Comment: @slashroot No nothing change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help it but to notice that your whole `checkAdmin` function has a style I haven't seen before. Let me try to simplify it a bit, maybe it helps with the issue.

```js
// Admin.js

// Return a Promise, so it's easier
// to deal with the asynchronous SQL Call

function checkAdmin (username) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    sql.execute(
      sql.format('SELECT * FROM tbl_admins'),
      (err, result, fields) => {

      if (err) { return reject(err); }

      let foundUser = false;
      result.map((element) => {
        if (element.Username == username) { foundUser = true; }
      });

      return resolve(foundUser);

    });

  });
}

module.exports = { checkAdmin };
```

First we return a Promise. Then we stay inside the callback function from the SQL call. If there is an error `err` we reject the Promise. If there is no error we resolve the Promise with a boolean `foundUser`. If we find the wanted username inside the table `foundUser` will be `true`, otherwise it will be `false`.

Now keep in mind that `checkAdmin` returns a Promise now.

```js
// Router Controller

const Admin = require('./Admin');

app.post('/some-route-only-admins-can-use', (req, res) => {
   
  const username = req.body.username;

  Admin.checkAdmin(username)
  .then((isAdmin) => {
  
    if (isAdmin) {
      return res.status(200).send({
        message: 'Access granted'
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: 'Access denied'
      });
    }

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    logger.error(err.message);
  });

});
```

This might differ from your code but it should give your the right idea hopefully.

#### Problem with your code

The main issue with your original `checkAdmin` method is that the SQL call is asynchronous. In your code you don't wait for it to finish, but you instantly return `admin` which at that point will always be `null`. And `null == false`.

Don't think about `this` too much. You normally don't need to alter it or use it.